# How to get valid token from api from auth0 client?

Tags: php, token, auth0

I am using emberjs with auth0 to log in.
Normally I enter username and password and I get a valid token which I send to api etc.

Now, I want to write some tests on api and I always need a valid token. My token expires in a day. So to run tests I always have to manually change the token sample.

So I want to get a token somehow from api? is possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good question. An easy way to do this for tests, is to use a [Client Credentials Grant Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/client-credentials). Since you want an access token from within a test, you can treat this as a machine to machine flow.

Here is an example where I am doing this from a test [to receive an Auth0 Management API v2 access token](https://github.com/tawawa/auth0-api-node-calls/blob/master/auth0-api/api.js#L4). And the [corresponding test too](https://github.com/tawawa/auth0-api-node-calls/blob/master/test/test.js#L16). And here is where I use that access token lookup [as part of a separate test](https://github.com/tawawa/auth0-api-node-calls/blob/master/test/test.js#L42). However, the same principle applies whether it the Auth0 specific Management API or an API you have defined yourself in the Auth0 Dashboard (under APIs) using a Non-Interactive Client and your own audience.

The "shape" of the call is pretty much as follows:

```
{ 
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://{TENANT}.auth0.com/oauth/token',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
  body: '{
         "client_id":"{CLIENT ID}",
         "client_secret":"{CLIENT SECRET}, 
         "audience":"https://{tenant}.auth0.com/api/v2/",
         "grant_type":"client_credentials"
  }' 
};
```

You call the `oauth/token` endpoint, and pass clientId, clientSecret, audience (for that api), and grant-type (`client_credentials`). If doing this with emberjs / php - it is very similar - If you create a new Client in Auth0 Dashboard and choose `Non Interactive` client type, then hit `Quick Start` - it will guide you through setup (if needed). See screenshot below, and feel free to leave comments if you have any probs.

[image]